# Looking for more efficient way to parse subprocess stdout

Tags: python-3.x

The code below is the stdout of a subprocess which gives me the result I want which is "You are connected to Australia #685 (au685.nordvpn.com)", but I'd like to learn a more efficient way to do it. I tried to split the string at "-|/-" but I can't get it to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
import re

result = """-  -  -  New feature - Meshnet! Link remote devices in Meshnet 
to connect to them directly over encrypted private tunnels, and 
route your traffic through another device. Use the `nordvpn meshnet --help` 
command to get started. Learn more: https://nordvpn.com/features/meshnet/-\|/-\|/-\|  
Connecting to Australia #685 (au685.nordvpn.com)-\|/-\  You are 
connected to Australia #685 (au685.nordvpn.com)!-"""

result = (re.sub('[-|/\\\!]', ' ', result))
result =  (" ".join(result.split()).lstrip())
result = (re.sub(r"New.+meshnet", "", result))
result = (result.lstrip())
result = result.split(") ")[1]

print (result)
```

Comment: How do you know that it is not efficient ??

Comment: I don't find your comment helpful. I don't know if its inefficient. I'm not a skilled python programmer and I assumed that if it takes 5 lines to extract what I want, there may be an easier method. If someone tells me that I can't get better than this then I'll leave it as is.